# Python Code Error

Tags: python

What's wrong with this program in Python?

I need to take an integer input(N) - accordingly, I need to create an array of (N)integers, taking integers also as input. Finally, I need to print the sum of all the integers in the array.

The input is in this format:

```
5

4 6 8 18 96
```

This is the code I wrote :

```
N = int(input().split())
i=0
s = 0
V=[]
if N<=100 :
    for i in range (0,N):
        x = int(input().split())
        V.append(x)
        i+=1
        s+=x
print (s)
```

Its showing the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
N = int(input().split())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) returns a list

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: If you need a list, `list(n)` will create a list, other then hat I have no idea what you're asking?

Comment: I have written what I need to do. What part are you not able to understand ?

Answer (score 6):

`split()` returns a list which you are trying to convert to an integer.
You probably wanted to convert everything in the list to an integer:

```
N = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

You can also use `map`:

```
N = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use sys module to take the input when calling the program and a lambda function to convert the string items in list to integers. You could also make use of the built-in sum function. Something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
s = sum(i for i in map(lambda x: int(x), sys.argv[1].split(',')))
print s
```

Example:

```
python test.py 1,2,3,4
```

The output should be **10**.

> Modifying your code:

Now, if you want to modify your code to do what it intends to do, you could modify your code like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

N = input()
s = 0
V=[]
if N<=100 :
    for i in range (0,N):
        x = input()
        V.append(x)
        s+=x
print (s)
```

**Note 1**: In python when you use range you don't have to manually increase the counter in the loop, it happens by default.

**Note 2**: the '`input()`' function will maintain the type of the variable you will enter, so if you enter an integer you don't have to convert it to integer. (Have in mind that `input()` is **not recommended to use** as it can be dangerous in more complicated projects).

**Note 3**: You don't need to use '`.split()`' for your input.

Comment: `list` is a Python builtin, you could use `lst` instead

Comment: @Moses Koledoye, my silly mistake!! just updated the answer, thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

You code fails because str.split() returns a list.
[From the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
>   string

If your input is a series of numbers as strings:

```
1 2 3 4
```

You'll want to iterate over the list returned by input.split() to do something with each integer.

```
in = input()
for num in in.split():
    x.append(int(num))
```

The result of this will be:
    x = [1,2,3,4]

Comment: `input` is a Python builtin. You probably want to call it, and that on a different line.

Comment: Ah, I didn't click that. Thanks